# textView1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I have this error in eclipse.My code is this.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        t1.setText("Hello");
    }
```

}

XML code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Help me to give the solution.

Comment: clean and build your project.

Comment: @MithilAmin Can you post your xml code?

Comment: @MithilAmin, please post your activity_main.xml file

Comment: @MithilAmin Your Code looks ok. As M D said, try cleaning and rebuilding your code.

Comment: delete all data? like c:\user\MITHIL\workspace   ?

Comment: lol...no Under Build->Clean Project

Comment: @MithilAmin: no first name sure you are not importing `android.R` if importing then remove it and and press `CTRL+SHIFT+O` for importing your on project R fo;e